# jquery ready suppress errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have noticed that errors thrown from a function bound the ready() event are suppressed by catch (e) { }. In the flowing example, there is no error thrown:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        nosuchobject.fakemethod();       //intentionally cause major error
    });
</script>
```

I can work it around with my own try-catch block. But my question is why errors are suppressed in the first place? Is my workaround the best solution?

Comment: This is not the case for me in jQuery 1.7; http://jsfiddle.net/y98Qu/. What version are you seeing this in?

Comment: Please except answers...

Comment: Which browser are you using? When I tried Matt's jsfiddle in Chrome nothing happened - no errors reported. But when I opened the console then I got reference errors "nosuchobject is not defined".

Comment: @Matt Thanks. Your jsfiddle helped me debug this problem. It turned out that one of the programmers added a `catch (e) { }` block...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use try/catch block:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      try {
        nosuchobject.fakemethod();
      } catch (ex) {
        //do something with ex object
      }
    });
```

In this case you can handle all erros and depending on nature of the problem you can decide how to fix/avoid such error cases.